# Fill Fortran Module Data in C

Tags: c, fortran

I have a Fortran library with following structure:

```
module data
implicit none
real(8), allocatable :: x(:)
end module data

subroutine ff(y)
use data

do some stuff with x
end subroutine
```

the reason for introduce the module data is that `x` is large and there are more subroutines use x.

Usually, call this lib in Fortran is nothing but allocate `x` first then call `ff`. Now I want to call this lib from C, it is easy to use ISO_C_BINDING to call `ff` from C, but I don't know how to allocate and fill value for module data `x` in C, a working solution is that use a wrapper function, that reads C data and allocate `x` in Fortran, something like

```
subroutine cif(carray, n) bind(c)
use iso_c_binding, only: c_double, c_int
use data
implicit none
integer(c_int), intent(in) :: n
real(c_double), intent(in) :: carray(n)
X = carray
end subrountine
```

I think this wrapper function will allocate the global data `x` with size `n` and fill values stored in `carray`, but since `x` is large, here we essentially double store the same array, that is, in C, it is `carray`, and in Fortran is `x`, I wonder whether I can directly put the address of `carray` to `x` with a wrapper function, since I can not modify the Fortran lib.

Comment: I don't understand.  You propose a wrapper function written in Fortran and exposing a C binding.  That seems reasonable, but why does this function have to use module `data` differently than any other Fortran code would do?  Isn't it the point of such a wrapper that it can use the module naturally?

Comment: Since I want to allocate the `x` inside `data` with pass in `carray` in this wrapper, it works, but not satisfied.

Comment: What you area not satisfied it? Tell us the details.

Comment: Use the above wrapper `cif`, it will store the "large" array both in `carray` and `x`, I wonder whether we can directly access `carray` in fortran by reference? @VladimirF

Comment: Just create two subroutines. One for allocation and  one for accessing the values. I don't see any problem.

Comment: by doing so, there will be two memory address store the "large" array@VladimirF